# Show by example that $\sup(A) \sup(B) \neq \sup(C)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

My question is Show by example that $\sup(A) \sup(B) \neq \sup(C)$ in general.

where $A$ and $B$ are nonepmty bounded seubsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $C=\big\{ab \colon a \in A$ and $b \in B \big\}$

So I am wondering what I really need do. 
I started off by saying let $\alpha = \sup(A)$ and $\beta = \sup(B)$
We need to show $\alpha \beta \neq \sup(C)$
or $\alpha \beta \neq ab$.

Now do I just assign values to these supremums? Like give a specific example? or do i continue to just use arbitrary supremum $\alpha, \beta, a,b$

Comment: What happens if both $A$ and $B$ are sets of negative numbers? $\qquad$

Comment: `Like give a specific example?` The title says "*show by example*".

Comment: You can't "just assign" values to sup.  I can't "just decide" sup (3,17) = e to the pi.

Answer (score 4):

You want to find a counterexample. The first thing that comes to my mind is the fact that a product of negative numbers is positive and therefore greater than any negative number. What if $A=B=[-1,0]$?

Comment: What if $A = B = \{-1\}$? :P

Comment: Um.  No it doesn't.  Sup A = sup B =-1.  C ={1}.  sup C =1 = sup A sup B.

Comment: @fleablood: Oy. Indeed. Doing too many things at once again.

Comment: @Neal: (Let’s get this right this time.) Indeed. The idea is merely the starting point. (Though one will be okay as long as $A,B\subseteq(\leftarrow,0]$, at least one of the sets has more than one element, and the other isn’t $\{0\}$.)

Answer (score 3):

How about

$$A = B = (-2,-1)?$$

Then $\sup A = \sup B = -1$ and $\sup A \sup B = 1$.

However $\sup C = 4$.